# HTML5 wrapper only wraps Header (using border)

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I used a border to figure out that my  wrapper is only wrapping my Header and I'm stumped as to why...I want to wrap the Header, all the way down to the footer...  Anyone have any pointers?

I've seen a lot of articles say to specify a width and the height is set to auto if not stated, too, right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <title>Personal Transportation/Errands Services</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div id="headleft">
        <img src="images/new logo flattened.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="headright">
        (717)***-****
            <br />
        ********@yahoo.com
    </div>
</header>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <article>
        Test
    </article>

    <aside>
        <img src="images/car 1.png" id="car" />
    </aside>

    <footer>
        Ftest
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
/* Makeshift CSS Reset */
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    /* Tell the browser to render HTML 5 elements as block */
    footer, header, aside, nav, article {
    display: block;
    }

body{
width:940px;
height: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
}

header {
background-color: #1a8cff;
}

nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: right;
background-color: #ff7f00;
font-family: bold 'Oswald', sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
color: #FFFF00;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
color: #FFFF00;
}

#headleft {
display:inline;
background-color: #1a8cff;
width: 100%;
}

#headright {
height: 87px;
padding-top: 37.5px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline;
float: right;
background-color: #1a8cff;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
}

body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
font: 13px/22px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
background-size: 100%;
}

article{
float: left;
}

aside{
float: right;
}

footer{
float:left;
background-color: #1a8cff;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clear your floated elements, you can use a clearfix or an empty `div` set to `clear:both`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2gbxdy2/)

You could also use a wrapper inside the `body` that wraps every element on the page and set that to `overflow: hidden`

[ALT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2gbxdy2/1/)

Comment: Thank you Fiddle,but I don't think it has worked correctly...  Going through it again...  Are you able to give me an example?  I've never used such an option.

Comment: huh? im not sure i understand what you're saying. what's not working correctly?